# Login to portal.azure.com needs microsoft account? How to access with external user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to manage a Microsoft Azure subscription as external user.

I followed various guides, added email (is not Microsoft account) in Azure Active Directory external users, sent email invitation, accepted invitation and finally landed on https://applications.microsoft.com but is not what i want, i need to login to https://portal.azure.com and it requires email and password (that i haven't) to login.

Where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: For my understanding and according to the official Azure documentation on Azure portal sign-in options, "By default, you sign in to the Azure portal with a Microsoft account. This account can be a work or school account or a personal Microsoft account."
In order to login with your guest user ([Authentication and Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/authentication-conditional-access)), you should authenticate with your IdP first.
Is your IdP still available? Do you have the correct permissions to handle the subscription?

Answer (score 0):

External users will receive an invitation email and, once they click accept, they will be landing to https://applications.microsoft.com,buy they can use their email address to log in to https://portal.azure.com now. Microsoft will send a one-time login password to his email before setting up the password.
Of course, you need to give them directory access permissions.